# List items lost between Click Events

Tags: asp.net

At the top of my code behind, I have the following code:

```
public class ImgData
{
    public byte[] Image  { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

List<ImageData> list = new List<ImageData>();
```

I have 2 Click Events

In one of the them I have the following code:

```
     protected void btnAttendee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        ImageData data = new ImageData();
        data.Category = "HR";
        data.Image = imgByte1;

        list.Add(data);

        int cnt = list.Count(); // Count show 1 once I click here

      }
```

In another place, I have the following code which I fire after the click event above:

```
   protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        // When I try to retreive the cnt it shows 0 here. I am not deleting any items on the list so not sure why it did not retain what was in the list

        int cnt = list.Count(); // should have count of 1 or more

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications are stateless.

What this means in the context of ASP.NET is that each time you make a new request to the server, a *new instance* of your page class is created.  So any instance members you populated with data last time are gone.  That previous instance was destroyed as soon as the resulting page was sent to the client.

In order to retain data across page requests, you have to persist it somewhere.  You have options in that regard:

- Page state (client-side)
- Session state
- Some application-level cache
- Database
- File system
- etc.

Any option for persisting data is going to have its own pros and cons.  So it's really up to you to determine what's best for your needs.  As an example, if you were to persist the data in session state, you might write it like this:

```
protected void btnAttendee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageData data = new ImageData();
    data.Category = "HR";
    data.Image = imgByte1;

    list.Add(data);

    int cnt = list.Count(); // Count show 1 once I click here

    Session["myList"] = list;

}
```

Then retrieve it here:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ImageData> list = (List<ImageData>)Session["myList"];

    int cnt = list.Count(); // should have count of 1 or more

}
```

Given this, you may even re-strcuture your class a bit if the member no longer needs to be instance-level.  It might be better as simply a method-level variable.

Comment: David is there a way to declare the List as global. This way it is accessible throughout the form. This way, no Session variables are needed.

Comment: @NatePet: What do you mean by "global"?  Where exactly would you be storing this information?  You don't *need* to use session state, that was just an example.  But you do need to put the data somewhere in order to access it at a later time.

Comment: David I tweaked the question with a working copy in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571773/list-persist-content-throughout-form. Kindly see if you can assist.

Comment: @NatePet: In what way is that question any different from this one, for which there is already an answer?  Where are you still stuck?

Comment: Thanks David, I restructured it but still having same issue. Please advise. Thank you so much. Or should I tweak it here as it is a different approach I am using. Thank you. I have a very tight deadline and need to have it in production soon

Comment: @NatePet: The same problem still exists, and the same answer still applies.  If you want data to persist between two instances of a class, you need to store that data somewhere.  Once a variable falls out of scope, the value stored in that variable is lost.  Creating the variable again doesn't automatically restore that value.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like webforms code.

a click will cause a postback and you will lose any data you hold in your variables when the page refreshes. You'll need to use something else to store them between postbacks like Session or ViewState.

One thing to keep in mind, the ViewState is saved inside the html of the page so don't put too much stuff in it. It is however useful for small, temporary values.